# ElasticSearch in-memory for testing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, integration-testing

I would like to write some integration with ElasticSearch. For testing I would like to run in-memory ES.

I found some information in documentation, but without example how to write those kind of test. [Elasticsearch Reference [1.6] » Testing » Java Testing Framework » integration tests
«  unit tests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/integration-tests.html)

Also I found following article, but it's out of data. [Easy JUnit testing with Elastic Search](http://pedanttinen.blogspot.cz/2013/02/easy-junit-testing-with-elastic-search.html)

I looking example how to start and run ES in-memory and access to it over REST API.

Comment: I'd start looking at Elasticsearch's own test classes. For example, [this one](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.6.0/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/test/ElasticsearchSingleNodeTest.java) where the index store type can be [set to `ram`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.6.0/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/test/ElasticsearchSingleNodeTest.java#L139).

Answer (score 8):

Based on [the second link](http://pedanttinen.blogspot.cz/2013/02/easy-junit-testing-with-elastic-search.html) you provided, I created this abstract test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractElasticsearchTest {

    private static final String HTTP_PORT = "9205";
    private static final String HTTP_TRANSPORT_PORT = "9305";
    private static final String ES_WORKING_DIR = "target/es";

    private static Node node;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startElasticsearch() throws Exception {    
        removeOldDataDir(ES_WORKING_DIR + "/" + clusterName);

        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("path.home", ES_WORKING_DIR)
                .put("path.conf", ES_WORKING_DIR)
                .put("path.data", ES_WORKING_DIR)
                .put("path.work", ES_WORKING_DIR)
                .put("path.logs", ES_WORKING_DIR)
                .put("http.port", HTTP_PORT)
                .put("transport.tcp.port", HTTP_TRANSPORT_PORT)
                .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
                .put("index.number_of_replicas", "0")
                .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "false")
                .build();
        node = nodeBuilder().settings(settings).clusterName("monkeys.elasticsearch").client(false).node();
        node.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopElasticsearch() {
        node.close();
    }

    private static void removeOldDataDir(String datadir) throws Exception {
        File dataDir = new File(datadir);
        if (dataDir.exists()) {
            FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(dataDir);
        }
    }    
}
```

In the production code, I configured an Elasticsearch client as follows. The integration test extends the above defined abstract class and configures property `elasticsearch.port` as `9305` and `elasticsearch.host` as `localhost`.

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {    
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public Client elasticsearchClient(@Value("${elasticsearch.clusterName}") String clusterName,
                                      @Value("${elasticsearch.host}") String elasticsearchClusterHost,
                                      @Value("${elasticsearch.port}") Integer elasticsearchClusterPort) throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
        InetSocketTransportAddress transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elasticsearchClusterHost), elasticsearchClusterPort);
        return TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(transportAddress);
    }
}
```

That's it. The integration test will run the production code which is configured to connect to the node started in the `AbstractElasticsearchTest.startElasticsearch()`.

In case you want to use the elasticsearch REST api, use port 9205. E.g. with Apache HttpComponents:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://localhost:9205/_template/" + templateName);
httpPut.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("template.json")));
httpClient.execute(httpPut);
```

Comment: For those coming in there, it looks like in ES 5.x they removed the NodeBuilder.  I am not sure if there is a way to run ES directly from your unit tests any longer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder;

/**
 *
 * @author Raghu Nair
 */
public final class ElasticSearchInMemory {

    private static Client client = null;
    private static File tempDir = null;
    private static Node elasticSearchNode = null;

    public static Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        tempDir = File.createTempFile("elasticsearch-temp", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));
        tempDir.delete();
        tempDir.mkdir();
        System.out.println("writing to: " + tempDir);

        String clusterName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        elasticSearchNode = NodeBuilder
                .nodeBuilder()
                .local(false)
                .clusterName(clusterName)
                .settings(
                        ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("script.disable_dynamic", "false")
                        .put("gateway.type", "local")
                        .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
                        .put("index.number_of_replicas", "0")
                        .put("path.data", new File(tempDir, "data").getAbsolutePath())
                        .put("path.logs", new File(tempDir, "logs").getAbsolutePath())
                        .put("path.work", new File(tempDir, "work").getAbsolutePath())
                ).node();
        elasticSearchNode.start();
        client = elasticSearchNode.client();
    }

    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
        if (elasticSearchNode != null) {
            elasticSearchNode.stop();
            elasticSearchNode.close();
        }
        if (tempDir != null) {
            removeDirectory(tempDir);
        }
    }

    public static void removeDirectory(File dir) throws IOException {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File aFile : files) {
                    removeDirectory(aFile);
                }
            }
        } 
        Files.delete(dir.toPath());        
    }
}
```

Comment: This no more works on ES 5.X They removed NodeBuilder

Comment: I am guessing we can still workaround using Node(settings).start();

Answer (score 2):

You can start ES on your local with:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("path.home", ".")
        .build();
NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(settings).node();
```

When ES started, access it over REST like:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016 embedded elasticsearch is [no-longer supported](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server#_embedded_elasticsearch_not_supported)

As per a [response from one of the devlopers in 2017](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/in-memory-testing-with-resthighlevelclient/106196/6) you can use the following approaches:

- Use the Gradle tools elasticsearch already has. You can read some information about this here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21119
- Use the Maven plugin: https://github.com/alexcojocaru/elasticsearch-maven-plugin
- Use Ant scripts like http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/10/18/elasticsearch-real-integration-tests-updated-for-ga
- Using Docker: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch
- Using Docker from maven: https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/blob/e15dddf72b1ed094dad279d492e4e0314f73683f/pom.xml#L241-L289